# Return a sequence of a variable length whose summation is equal to a given integer

Tags: python, math, permutation, combinations

In the form `f(x,y,z)` where `x` is a given integer sum, `y` is the minimum length of the sequence, and `z` is the maximum length of the sequence. But for now let's pretend we're dealing with a sequence of a fixed length, because it will take me a long time to write the question otherwise.

So our function is `f(x,r)` where `x` is a given integer sum and `r` is the length of a sequence in the list of possible sequences.

For `x = 10`, and `r = 2`, these are the possible combinations:

```
1 + 9
2 + 8
3 + 7
4 + 6
5 + 5
```

Let's store that in Python as a list of pairs:

```
[(1,9), (2,8), (3,7), (4,6), (5,5)]
```

So usage looks like:

```
>>> f(10,2)
[(1,9), (2,8), (3,7), (4,6), (5,5)]
```

Back to the original question, where a sequence is return for each length in the range `(y,x)`. I the form `f(x,y,z)`, defined earlier, and leaving out sequences of length `1` (where `y-z == 0`), this would look like:

```
>>> f(10,1,3)
[{1: [(1,9), (2,8), (3,7), (4,6), (5,5)],
  2: [(1,1,8), (1,2,7), (1,3,6) ... (2,4,4) ...],
  3: [(1,1,1,7) ...]}]
```

So the output is a list of dictionaries where the value is a list of pairs. Not exactly optimal.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a library that handles this already?
2. If not, can someone help me write both of the functions I mentioned? (fixed sequence length first)?
3. Because of the huge gaps in my knowledge of fairly trivial math, could you ignore my approach to integer storage and use whatever structure the makes the most sense?

Sorry about all of these arithmetic questions today. Thanks!

Comment: the output is a list of tuples

Comment: Do you really need to generate the full list of sequences?  That seems a bit unwieldy (not to mention slow)...  Perhaps a better way to look at this is to write a function `g(sum, nterms, index)` that returns the `index`th sequence of a sorted list of all sequences of length `nterms` that sum to `sum`.  I think this would be easier - and I strongly suspect that it'll end up being recursive.

Comment: Output is now a list of dictionaries, which was my original intention.

Comment: Do you want a random sequence or all sequences? Either the title or the description needs to change.

Comment: Shoot, sorry. I can do the random bit on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module will definately be helpful as we're dealing with premutations - however, this looks suspiciously like a homework task...

**Edit**: Looks like fun though, so I'll do an attempt.

**Edit 2**: This what you want?

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from pprint import pprint

f = lambda target_sum, length: [sequence for sequence in combinations_with_replacement(range(1, target_sum+1), length) if sum(sequence) == target_sum]

def f2(target_sum, min_length, max_length):
    sequences = {}
    for length in range(min_length, max_length + 1):
        sequence = f(target_sum, length)
        if len(sequence):
            sequences[length] = sequence
    return sequences

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("f(10,2):")
    print(f(10,2))
    print()
    print("f(10,1,3)")
    pprint(f2(10,1,3))
```

Output:

```
f(10,2):
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5)]

f(10,1,3)
{1: [(10,)],
 2: [(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5)],
 3: [(1, 1, 8),
     (1, 2, 7),
     (1, 3, 6),
     (1, 4, 5),
     (2, 2, 6),
     (2, 3, 5),
     (2, 4, 4),
     (3, 3, 4)]}
```

Comment: f, f2, r, c... I think you should use meaningful words for your variables or functions.

Comment: The OP only named them f, and I couldn't really think of anything more logical...

Comment: Not my homework in itself, but it does compute my homework. (Which is in no way cheating.)

Comment: @odonnel So is this what you need?

Comment: Okay, but output should be separated into sequences of a consistent length like in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is known as **[Integer Partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)**, and has been widely studied.

**[Here](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~ivan/F49-int-part.pdf)** you can find a paper comparing the performance of several algorithms (and proposing a particular one), but there are a lot of references all over the Net.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a recursive generator function, you should figure out how to get a list out of it yourself...

```
def f(x,y):
    if y == 1:
        yield (x, )
    elif y > 1:
        for head in range(1, x-y+2):
            for tail in f(x-head, y-1):
                yield tuple([head] + list(tail))

def f2(x,y,z):
    for u in range(y, z+1):
        for v in f(x, u):
            yield v
```

EDIT: I just see it is not exactly what you wanted, my version also generates duplicates where only the ordering differs. But you can simply filter them out by ordering all results and check for duplicate tuples.